# Silverlight redirecting between project pages

Tags: silverlight, redirect, navigation

I am having a my problem is I can not redirect my page in silverlight like most of people who are not familiar with this technology .

I design a login page first and if password is correct I want it to direct to MainPage.xaml

[image]

as you can see I tried methods which are commented already it did not work . I searched in this web page there are some posts about this problem but I could not solve please help me .

when i try that one;

```
Uri target = new Uri("MainPage",UriKind.Relative);
NavigationService.Navigate(target);
```

error message : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

actually we found a solution with my friend ;

instead of directing a web page , when code goes into if block we are changing the content of page with {this.Content = new MainPage() ; } method and it is working .But System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(target) this one is directing us same login page or pages like www.---.com outside normal html pages .

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to use the NavigationService to do this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage", UriKind.Relative));
```

The NavigationService is a property on the Page object so it will be available in the Login code-behind.

However, after you mentioned that you've "already done this" I realized the issue. Silverlight Navigation uses a Frame control. This Frame control lives in MainPage.xaml for the default project. So you're not navigating inside the frame, but you want to change the entire screen to a different one and do so without the Navigation services built into Silverlight.

I'd suggest you either (a) have the Login run as a page inside of the Frame on MainPage (you can load or unload the links on the top based on if the user is authenticated) or (b) don't use the Navigation for the remainder of the application and use a framework like Caliburn.Micro to handle all the Navigation between views.

Comment: I already tried that one from first place i indicated in the picture of my screen .

Comment: Updated based on this information. I assume you've modified the App.xaml.cs to set the Application RootVisual to a new Login view.

Comment: Not actually my App.xaml is   this.RootVisual = new Login(); in my login page when code goes to if block i change the content of a page so it is kind of fitting my aim now .However , still needs some commends about it .

Comment: Exactly, you're using Login.xaml as the root visual which means you're not using a Frame to navigate.